# Storing Artifacts From a Failed Build

Tags: google-cloud-build

I am running some screen diffing tests in one of my Cloud Build steps. The tests produce png files that I would like to view after the build, but it appears to upload artifacts on successful builds.

If my test fail, the process exits with a non-zero code, which results in this error:

```
ERROR: build step 0 "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
```

Which further results in another error

```
ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build a22d1ab5-c996-49fe-a782-a74481ad5c2a completed with status "FAILURE"
```

And no artifacts get uploaded.

I added `|| true` after my tests, so it exits successfully, and the artifacts get uploaded.

I want to:

- A) Confirm that this behavior is expected
- B) Know if there is a way to upload artifacts even if a step fails

Edit:

Here is my `cloudbuild.yaml`

```
options:
 machineType: 'N1_HIGHCPU_32'

timeout: 3000s

steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/skaffold'
  env:
  - 'CLOUD_BUILD=1'
  entrypoint: bash
  args:
  - -x  # print commands as they are being executed
  - -c  # run the following command...
  - build/test/smoke/smoke-test.sh


artifacts:
  objects:
    location: 'gs://cloudbuild-artifacts/$BUILD_ID'
    paths: [
      '/workspace/build/test/cypress/screenshots/*.png'
    ]
```

Comment: Could you please share your cloudbuild.yaml file to better look how are you trying to upload artifacts? Thanks

Comment: Hi @NibrassH I updated the post to include cloudbuild.yaml

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Google Cloud Build doesn't allow us to upload artifacts (or run some steps ) if a build step fails. This is the expected behavior.

There is an already feature request created in [Public Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128353446) to allow us to run some steps even though the build has finished or failed. Please feel free to star it to get all the related updates on this issue.

A workaround per now is as you mentioned using || true after the tests or use || exit 0 as mentioned in this [Github issue](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloud-builders/issues/253#issuecomment-381600420).

Comment: Google must be kidding us. I have no words to express how awful the Google Cloud Build product is. How can they go in prod without that feature? Real-life case: I can't view the integration test video with a detailed log. Hence I have limited abilities to debug the failed test. Shame.

Comment: echoing that - two years later and this most basic feature is still not available.

Comment: I came across this today and wanted to add that this feature has been added, about two months after the most recent comment.